# Testing Spring's @RequestBody using Spring MockMVC

Tags: spring-mvc, integration-testing

I am trying to test a method that posts an object to the database using Spring's MockMVC framework.  I've constructed the test as follows:

```
@Test
public void testInsertObject() throws Exception { 

    String url = BASE_URL + "/object";

    ObjectBean anObject = new ObjectBean();
    anObject.setObjectId("33");
    anObject.setUserId("4268321");
    //... more

    Gson gson = new Gson();
    String json = gson.toJson(anObject);

    MvcResult result = this.mockMvc.perform(
            post(url)
            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
            .content(json))
            .andExpect(status().isOk())
            .andReturn();
}
```

The method I'm testing uses Spring's @RequestBody to receive the ObjectBean, but the test always returns a 400 error.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(    consumes="application/json",
                    produces="application/json",
                    method=RequestMethod.POST,
                    value="/object")
public ObjectResponse insertObject(@RequestBody ObjectBean bean){

    this.photonetService.insertObject(bean);

    ObjectResponse response = new ObjectResponse();
    response.setObject(bean);

    return response;
}
```

The json created by gson in the test:

```
{
   "objectId":"33",
   "userId":"4268321",
   //... many more
}
```

The ObjectBean class

```
public class ObjectBean {

private String objectId;
private String userId;
//... many more

public String getObjectId() {
    return objectId;
}

public void setObjectId(String objectId) {
    this.objectId = objectId;
}

public String getUserId() {
    return userId;
}

public void setUserId(String userId) {
    this.userId = userId;
}
//... many more
}
```

So my question is: how to I test this method using Spring MockMVC?

Comment: You will have to post the actual class. With a 400, Spring is failing to convert your request body to an `ObjectBean` object.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, it's a date format issue I'm looking into.  I'm passing a java.util Date and gson doesn't like it.

Comment: Hi Sotirios.  Yeah, unfortunately this problem persists!  I've asked a question concerning the date format here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20509883/mysql-insert-gson-date

Comment: What is the type of the date field in the `ObjectBean` class? `java.util.Date`, `java.util.Calendar`, or `String`? Or some other?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

**Use this one**

```
public static final MediaType APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 = new MediaType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getType(), MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON.getSubtype(), Charset.forName("utf8"));

@Test
public void testInsertObject() throws Exception { 
    String url = BASE_URL + "/object";
    ObjectBean anObject = new ObjectBean();
    anObject.setObjectId("33");
    anObject.setUserId("4268321");
    //... more
    ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
    mapper.configure(SerializationFeature.WRAP_ROOT_VALUE, false);
    ObjectWriter ow = mapper.writer().withDefaultPrettyPrinter();
    String requestJson=ow.writeValueAsString(anObject );

    mockMvc.perform(post(url).contentType(APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8)
        .content(requestJson))
        .andExpect(status().isOk());
}
```

As described in the comments, this works because the object is converted to json and passed as the request body. Additionally, the contentType is defined as Json (APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8).

[More info on the HTTP request body structure](http://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#Body)

Comment: @WendyG Because the object is converted to json and passed as the request body (additionally, the contentType is defined as Json). More info on the HTTP request body structure here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Messages#Body

Comment: @JonyD I have been told off for not attributing comment writers in the answer before, but sorry I got your name wrong.

Comment: Why not just use MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON? MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8 also exists but it's been deprecated since 5.2

Answer (score 52):

the following works for me,

```
  mockMvc.perform(
            MockMvcRequestBuilders.post("/api/test/url")
                    .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                    .content(asJsonString(createItemForm)))
            .andExpect(status().isCreated());

  public static String asJsonString(final Object obj) {
    try {
        return new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(obj);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9):

The issue is that you are serializing your bean with a custom `Gson` object while the application is attempting to deserialize your JSON with a Jackson `ObjectMapper` (within `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter`).

If you open up your server logs, you should see something like

```
Exception in thread "main" com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Can not construct instance of java.util.Date from String value '2013-34-10-10:34:31': not a valid representation (error: Failed to parse Date value '2013-34-10-10:34:31': Can not parse date "2013-34-10-10:34:31": not compatible with any of standard forms ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", "EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss zzz", "yyyy-MM-dd"))
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@baea1ed; line: 1, column: 20] (through reference chain: com.spring.Bean["publicationDate"])
```

among other stack traces.

One solution is to set your `Gson` date format to one of the above (in the stacktrace).

The alternative is to register your own `MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter` by configuring your own `ObjectMapper` to have the same date format as your `Gson`.

Comment: Thanks Sotirios, this is a very helpful lesson.  I had assumed that the deserialization would just take the format that I listed: yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss.  Is this because the @RequestBody uses Jackson?  Also, this answers my other question that I linked above...

Comment: @MattB There are 2 different processes involved. You are serializing in on process with the format you specified. You are deserializing in a separate application that is using its own format.

Answer (score 9):

I have encountered a similar problem with a more recent version of Spring. I tried to use a `new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(...)` but it would not work in my case.

I actually had a `String` in a JSON format, but I feel like it is literally transforming the `toString()` method of every field into JSON. In my case, a date `LocalDate` field would end up as:

> "date":{"year":2021,"month":"JANUARY","monthValue":1,"dayOfMonth":1,"chronology":{"id":"ISO","calendarType":"iso8601"},"dayOfWeek":"FRIDAY","leapYear":false,"dayOfYear":1,"era":"CE"}

which is not the best date format to send in a request ...

In the end, the simplest solution in my case is to use the Spring `ObjectMapper`. Its behaviour is better since it uses Jackson to build your JSON with complex types.

```
@Autowired
private ObjectMapper objectMapper;
```

and I simply used it in my test:

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/api/")
                .content(objectMapper.writeValueAsString(...))
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
);
```

Comment: I have done this, but its not working at all in my case, I have seen it is formatting th e class properly,  Its just that it is printing bad request

Answer (score 1):

You can also get easly json content from file, it is helpful when content is big.

You can create common package and add static method

```
public static String getRequestBodyFromFile(String fileLocation) throws IOException {
        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile(String.format("classpath:%s", fileLocation));
        return new String(Files.readAllBytes(file.toPath()));
    }
```

and then just add file to your test resources and load at test

```
mockMvc.perform(post("/yourpath")
                            .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
                            .content(getRequestBodyFromFile("resourcespath/yourjsonfile.json")))
                .andExpect(status()
                        .isOk())
```

hope will be helpful for someone.