# MySQL Insert Gson Date

Tags: java, mysql, gson, mybatis

If I have serialized a class into json, which contains dates, using gson, how can I use the value of the json to insert into my h2 or MySQL database using MyBatis?

The json below is constructed using the following code:

```
Bean bean = new Bean();
bean.setIsPublished(true);
bean.setPublicationDate(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss").create();
String json = gson.toJson(bean);
```

Which makes json:

```
{
   "isPublished":true,
   "publicationDate":"2013-55-10-09:55:07"
}
```

But when I pass this json to my insert statement (using spring's @RequestBody to construct the Bean) the service returns a 400: Bad Syntax.

Here's the MyBatis Mapper's insert statement:

```
INSERT INTO beans (isPublished, publicationDate)
VALUES (#{isPublished}, parseDateTime(#{publicationDate}, 'yyyy-mm-dd-hh:mm:ss');
```

When I'm trying to insert the parsed json date, something is going wrong, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: You're trying to parseDateTime on a boolean?

Comment: Sorry, Typo.  I've updated.

Comment: The application is never hitting your insert statement, it fails to deserialize your JSON date.

Answer (score 2):

Just use the Mysql date_format function and let the database do it for you

```
 date_format( #{publicationDate, jdbcType=VARCHAR}, '%Y-%m-%d-%H-%i-%s' )
```