# How to use Gson instead of Jackson for MockMvc?

Tags: java, jackson, gson, mockmvc

I have spent the past day trying to find a solution to this and could not find any online resource that solves this.

I am using Gson for Message conversion for my application, which works fine outside of unit testing. I even added a `HttpMessageConverters` bean to take precedence over Jackson instead of writing config values to `application.yml`. This only works when running the application.

Now my question is, how do I use the Gson serialization/deserialization for `MockMvc`? I have a class with the `@SerializedName("field_one")` annotation which the value differs from the actual name. The closest I got to finding an answer was the one below which didn't help:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/20510028/3948882

Any ideas how to replace the `ObjectMapper` or have `MockMvc` use Gson instead of Jackson?

---

Edit: To add a little more context:

When I try to send a `Model` which was converted to Json with Gson, it get's immediately refused (400) because I have `@NotNull` annotation for each field in the model. When it deserializes in the controller, it sets fields to null. The below example has `@Valid`, which makes sure the `Model` checks out.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "accept", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Model resp(@Valid @RequestBody Model model){
    return model;
}
```

On the flip side, when I go to hit an endpoint without `@Valid`, passing a json that pleases Jackson, and I get the a model back, I cannot check any of the fields:

```
mockMvc.perform(
    post("/test/accept")
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
        .content(json))
    .andExpect(jsonPath("$.field_one", is("Hello world!")))
```

Exception:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: No value at JSON path "$.field_one", exception: No results for path: $['field_one']
```

Comment: I am also looking for a solution for this problem. Anything you found?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31883657/customized-objectmapper-not-used-in-test
refer this

Comment: @SarthakVerma see the answer

Answer (score 2):

You have to set-up the `MockMvc` correctly:

```
MockMvc mvc = MockMvcBuilders.standaloneSetup(new YourController())
                             .setControllerAdvice(new SomeExceptionHandler())
                             .setMessageConverters(new GsonHttpMessageConverter()) //<-- THIS
                             .build();
```